# jquery mobile for mobile without postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile controls and i have two buttons save and cancel.On clicking save i want to save data to database.But i want to write code using jquery and json so that page postback will not occur again and again on click of save button.Please give me some idea how to do this and save data to database.
  My code is

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
    </title>
    <link href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        /* App custom styles */
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- Items Assessment -->
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="d" id="page10">
        <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" href="page22" data-icon="home"
            data-iconpos="right" class="ui-btn-right">
                Home
            </a>
            <a data-role="button" data-transition="slide" href="page3.html" data-
icon="arrow-l"
            data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
                Back
            </a>
            <h3>
            </h3>
            <div class="ui-title">
                <img style="QuickMove.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="selectmenu29"><span style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Room Type:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <select name="selectmenu29" id="selectmenu29" data-theme="b" 
data-mini="true" runat="server">
                            <option value="option1">
                                Room Type
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput43"><span style="font-family: times   
new roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Building &amp; Floor:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="" id="textinput43" placeholder="" value="" 
type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="selectmenu31"><span style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Origin:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <select name="selectmenu31" id="selectmenu31" data-theme="b" 
data-mini="true">
                            <option value="option1">
                                ALL
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="selectmenu33"><span style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <strong>
                                    Destination:
                                </strong>
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <select name="selectmenu33" id="selectmenu33" data-theme="b" 
data-mini="true">
                            <option value="option1">
                                ALL
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" data-   
mini="true">
                            <legend> <span style="font-family: times new roman,times; 
font-size: medium;">
                                <strong>
                                    Transport Mode:
                                </strong>
                            </span>
                            </legend>
                            <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio1" value="radio1" 
type="radio">
                            <label for="radio1">
                                Road
                            </label>
                            <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio2" value="radio2" 
type="radio">
                            <label for="radio2">
                                Air
                            </label>
                            <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio3" value="radio3" 
type="radio">
                            <label for="radio3">
                                Sea
                            </label>
                            <input name="radiobuttons1" id="radio4" value="radio4" 
type="radio">
                            <label for="radio4">
                                Rail
                            </label>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>



                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput47"><span style="font-family: times 
new roman,times; font-size: medium;" data-mce-style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Quantity:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="" id="textinput47" placeholder="" value="" 
type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput73"><span style="font-family: times 
new roman,times; font-size: medium;" data-mce-style="font-family: times new 
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Width
                                </b>
                                <b>
                                    ​:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="" id="textinput73" placeholder="" value=""   
type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput74"><span style="font-family: times     

new roman,times; font-size: medium;" data-mce-style="font-family: times new   
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <strong>
                                    Height:
                                </strong>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="" id="textinput74" placeholder="" value=""   
type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">

                        </fieldset>
                    </div>


                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="selectmenu26">
                        </label>

                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
                            <label for="textinput76"> <span style="font-family: times   
new roman,times; font-size: medium;" data-mce-style="font-family: times new     
roman,times; font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Weight:
                                </b>
                            </span>
                            </label>
                            <input name="" id="textinput76" placeholder="" value="" type="text">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data- 

mini="true">
                            <legend><span style="font-family: times new roman,times;   
font-size: medium;">
                                <b>
                                    Packing Required?
                                </b>
                            </span>
                            </legend>


                        </fieldset>
                    </div>






                     <div class="ui-grid-a" style="width:100%">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="btn_save" data-   
transition="fade" data-theme="b"
                    href="#page12" data-icon="check" data-iconpos="right" >
                        Save
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b" >
                    <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade"  
  data-theme="b"
                    href="#page12" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="right" 
 runat="server">
                        Cancel
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

 </div> 
    </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just make an ajax post request to do that asynchronously.

```
// Encapsulate your input elements inside a form tag like 
// Get all the Parameters from the form 
var formData = $("#myForm").serialize();

$.ajax({
 url:,
 type:"post",
 data:formData,
 success:function(data){
  // Actions when the save was successful
 },
 error:function(object,txtStatus,errorThrown) {
  // Actions to handle the error thrown
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html), jquery mobile posts data via ajax whenever possible. You don't need to serialize your data to json for that.